# Conflict in hove and hadoop Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to run Hive on my linux machine and this error occurs. i'm installing hiva and hadoop and the conflict occured

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in \[jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class\]
SLF4J: Found binding in \[jar:file:/home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.35.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class\]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type \[org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory\]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)'
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1357)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1338)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.setJar(JobConf.java:536)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.setJarByClass(JobConf.java:554)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.\<init\>(JobConf.java:448)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.initialize(HiveConf.java:5144)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.\<init\>(HiveConf.java:5107)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.\<init\>(HiveSchemaTool.java:96)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.main(HiveSchemaTool.java:1473)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)

I tried everything to solve it but it didn't work`
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with SLF4J multiple bindings, but rather the Guava library.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.